# Collision and KeyPressed libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I am making an RPG style game with LibGDX and I want to change the screen when my player is both in contact with a door and presses the spacebar. I looked online for this literally everywhere but couldn't find it. Can someone please help?

World Contact Listener Class:

```
public class WorldContactListener implements ContactListener {
    @Override
    public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
        Fixture fixA= contact.getFixtureA();
        Fixture fixB= contact.getFixtureB();
            if (fixA.getUserData()=="head"||fixB.getUserData()=="head"){
                Fixture shape= fixA.getUserData()=="head"? fixA:fixB;
                Fixture object=shape==fixA? fixB:fixA;
                if(object.getUserData() instanceof InteractiveTileObject){
                    ((InteractiveTileObject)object.getUserData()).onHeadHit();
                }
            }

    }

    @Override
    public void endContact(Contact contact) {

    }

    @Override
    public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {

    }

    @Override
    public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {

    }
}
```

InteractiveTileObject (Class which makes the objects in box2d:

```
    public InteractiveTileObject(World world, TiledMap map, Rectangle bounds){
        this.world=world;
        this.map=map;
        this.bounds=bounds;

        BodyDef bdef= new BodyDef();
        FixtureDef fdef= new FixtureDef();
        PolygonShape shape= new PolygonShape();

        bdef.type=BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
        bdef.position.set((bounds.getX()+bounds.getWidth()/2)/ (2*MamsGame.PPM), (bounds.getY()+bounds.getHeight()/2)/(2*MamsGame.PPM));

        body=world.createBody(bdef);

        shape.setAsBox(bounds.getWidth()/2/ (2*MamsGame.PPM),bounds.getHeight()/2/(2*MamsGame.PPM));
        fdef.shape=shape;
        fixture=body.createFixture(fdef);
    }
    public abstract void onHeadHit();
}
```

DoorToSchool (Object that I want the player to collide with)

```
public class DoorToSchool extends InteractiveTileObject{
    public DoorToSchool(World world, TiledMap map, Rectangle bounds){
        super(world,map,bounds);
        fixture.setUserData(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHeadHit() {

        Gdx.app.log("DoorToSchool","Collison");


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ContactListener works this way (*i'm ignoring pre-post solve since you don't need them here*):

1. Contact occured
2. *ContactListener.beginContact* gets called

Then, **nothing happen until Contact broke** (after what *endContact* is called). And this is the period you want to listen for space key.

Just set a flag like `listenForSpaceKey` to true when *beginContact* is called. Then, in your game update loop, listen for space key only if `listenForSpaceKey` is set to true.

Set `listenForSpaceKey` to false when *endContact* is called. This way you're listening for space key only if a contact is in process.